# Knockout $root binding does not update UI element immediately

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to display `$root` on the page so I know what's in the object.
After the first add event, the added item is added to the object, but the UI does not reflect the change. Only on the second add event, the first item is displayed on UI, but the second one is not displayed until the third add event and so forth.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osrvsug9/)

HTML

```
<input type='text' data-bind='value: selectedItem' />
<input type='button' data-bind='click: addItem' value='add' />
<pre>vm = <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 4)"></span></pre>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var BaseVM = function () {
        var that = {};
        return that;
    };
    var TestVM = function () {
        var that = BaseVM();
        that.relatedItems = ko.observableArray(['pork', 'ham']);
        that.selectedItem = ko.observable('');
        that.addItem = function () {
            if (that.relatedItems().indexOf(that.selectedItem()) >= 0) {
                alert('existed');
            } else {
                that.relatedItems().push(that.selectedItem());
            }
        };
        that.removeItem = function () {
            if (that.relatedItems().indexOf(that.selectedItem()) >= 0) {
                that.relatedItems().remove(that.selectedItem());
            }
        };
        return that;
    };
    var vm = TestVM();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `.push` (and `.remove`) on the underlying JavaScript array, so Knockout doesn't see the change.  It's only when something else is causing the whole thing to rerender that it picks up the changes.

Knockout [redefines the array functions on observableArrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#pop-push-shift-unshift-reverse-sort-splice), and when you call them on those objects, it both updates the underlying array and notifies any subscribers.  Instead of this:

```
that.relatedItems().push(that.selectedItem());
```

You need this:

```
that.relatedItems.push(that.selectedItem());
```

Here it is with the changes:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var BaseVM = function () {
        var that = {};
        return that;
    };
    var TestVM = function () {
        var that = BaseVM();
        that.relatedItems = ko.observableArray(['pork', 'ham']);
        that.selectedItem = ko.observable('');
        that.addItem = function () {
            if (that.relatedItems().indexOf(that.selectedItem()) >= 0) {
                alert('existed');
            } else {
                that.relatedItems.push(that.selectedItem());
            }
        };
        that.removeItem = function () {
            if (that.relatedItems().indexOf(that.selectedItem()) >= 0) {
                that.relatedItems.remove(that.selectedItem());
            }
        };
        return that;
    };
    var vm = TestVM();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type='text' data-bind='value: selectedItem' />
<input type='button' data-bind='click: addItem' value='add' />
<pre>vm = <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 4)"></span></pre>
```